# Explanation of bitwise operations in c

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

So I've been working on this review problem and can't follow along that much with the provided answer.
I understand the operation they are doing to reverse the hexadecimal digits, however I'm lost on the method they use to get the next odd greater than it.

lines I'm confused about:

```
 unsigned char ones = !0; 
 ...
 ones = ones <<2 <<2;
 ones |= !0;
 results |= ones;
```

What is !0? Is this just not 0? and how do you shift/relate that to the other parts?

thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the C Standard (6.5.3.3 Unary arithmetic operators)

> 5 The result of the logical negation operator ! is 0 if the value of
>   its operand compares unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its operand
>   compares equal to 0. The result has type int. The expression !E is
>   equivalent to (0==E).

Thus `!0` yields 1.

Let's assume that the argument of the function is `0x3C`

After statement

```
unsigned char ones = !0;
```

`ones` will be equal to `0x01`

After statement

```
unsigned char result = val << 2 << 2;
```

`result` will be equal to `0xC0`

After statement

```
unsigned cgar temp = val >> 2 >> 2;
```

`temp` will be equal to `0x03`

After statement

```
result += temp;
```

`ewsult` will be equal to `0xC3`

That is `result` has the reverse value of `val` that in turn has `0x3C`

The remaining statements set the lowest bits of each hexadecimal digits to 1 For example

```
ones = ones << 2 << 2;
```

yields `0x10`

So you wll get that result will be equal to `0xD3` (3 has already the lowest bit equal to 1 and C will be converted to D).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should know that `!0` is an obfuscated way of saying `1` (or not `false`).

```
printf("%i\n", !0);
```

At one time C did not have `stdbool`

Comment: Ah ok, I wasn't sure why they wouldn't just put 1 but realized there was specifications in the problem. Hopefully I can work through it a little more now

Answer (score 0):

Well, just figured it out and understand this solution now. Here's what I've worked out and attempted to explain to myself. (ignoring the reverse since I think that's pretty simple compared to this part)

the ones = 0000 0001

once you shift that <<2 <<2 (<<4) it goes to 0001 0000

once you |= that with !0 (0000 0001) you get 0001 0001. That way it has a 1 in the (2^0) spot which is the odd part of the problem.

Then from there you |= the 0001 0001 with the reversed to make sure it's the next odd since x | 1 will be 1